# Changing Font in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to change font family and size in Tkinter but everytime when I change font size buttons size automatically get bigger. How can I fix that?

Note: I used .place() instead of .pack()

Comment: Do you change the font of the button or of another element?

Comment: You can specify the width and height in `.place()`.

Comment: I want to change font of the button.

Comment: If you specify the `width` and `height` options in `.place()` for the button, the size of the button will not be changed after changing the font size.